# differential function problem

Tags: real-analysis

I am not sure how to approach it,

Function $ f  $ continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$.

Prove that if  $c\in(a,b)$ and $f(c)=\min\{f(a),f(b)\}$.

There is $d\in(a,b)$ that $f'(d)=0$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use mean value theorem, without loss of generality let $f(a)$ be the minimum of the two, then $f(a)-f(c)=0$.

Then by MVT there is $d\in(a,c)$ such that $f'(d)=\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=0$

Answer (score 0):

The condition tells you that the function attains it's minimum in the interior of the interval.

This does not seem to be obvious to some commentators which, I have to say, makes me a bit sad. For those who do not see this: The function does take a minimum, since it is continuous and defined on a compact interval. This happens either at the boundary or in the interior. If it happens at the boundary, the condition on $c$ says that it also happens in $c$, that is, in the interior. Otherwise there is some $d_1$ such that $f(d_1)<f(c)$, hence the minimum value is at least as small and cannot occur at the boundary, so it is attained in an interior point.

In such a point the derivative vanishes.

Comment: The condition does not state this - it simply states that the function is equal to one of its boundary values at some interior point.

Comment: Not true. $|x|$ has a minimum at $x = 0$ but derivative isn't zero.

Comment: @user88595 the function is assumed to be differentiable in the interior.

Comment: @Ayesha it does, with one additional step.